# Converting datetime to dd/mm/yy h:m

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am trying to convert the below date and time to dd/mm/yy H:M using javascript.

`February 24th 2021, 15:21:46`

to

`24/02/2021 15:21`

I was trying -

```
moment('February 24th 2021, 15:21:46').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')
```

I am getting an invalid date.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The error isn't coming from formatting, it's coming from parsing the original date.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/), it looks like you should be using `moment('February 24th 2021, 15:21:46', 'MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss')`.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar

Comment: Thank you @AndrewMorton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Barmer said in their comment, it's not the formatting that is throwing the error.

You should tell moment what format the input is so it can be parsed.

```js
const formattedDate = moment('February 24th 2021, 15:21:46', 'MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss')
  .format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
  
console.log(formattedDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. I missed the second parameter.